# How to change the value of a prop (or data) of a component, from OUTSIDE the component?

Tags: vue.js, actioncable

As the title says, I'm trying to change the value of a prop/data in a component, but the trigger is being fired from outside the component, from something that has nothing to do with Vuejs.

Currently I trying to use a Simple State Manager, based on the docs from [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch), like so:

```
var store = {
  debug: true,
  state: {
    progress: 23
  },
  setProgress (uff) {
    if (this.debug) console.log(uff)
    this.state.progress = uff
  }
}
```

The documentation leads me to believe that if the value of `progress` is mutated, the value of my Vue instance would also change if I link them accordingly. But this doesn't work in a component (my guess would be it's cause it's a function).

This is part of my component:

```
Vue.component('transcoding', {
  data () {
    return {
      progress: store.state.progress
    }
  },
  template: `
    <v-progress-circular
        :size="130"
        :width="25"
        :value="progress"
        color="teal"
      >
      {{progress}}
    </v-progress-circular>
  `
})
```

So, when I trigger a `store.setProgress(value)`, nothing happens. The log messages do happen, but the state isn't updated in the component.

This is the script that's currently triggering the state change:

```
App.cable.subscriptions.create(
  { channel: "ProgressChannel", room: "2" },
  { received: function() {
    store.setProgress(arguments[0])
   }}
)
```

It's an ActionCable websocket in Ruby on Rails. The trigger works perfectly, but I just cannot make the connection between the state change and the component.

I tried loading this script in the `mounted()` event for the component, thinking I could reference the value like this:

```
Vue.component('transcoding', {
  data () {
    return {
      progress: 0
    }
  },
  template: `
    <v-progress-circular
        :size="130"
        :width="25"
        :value="progress"
        color="teal"
      >
      {{progress}}
    </v-progress-circular>
  `,
  methods: {
    setProgress: function(uff) {
      this.progress = uff
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    App.cable.subscriptions.create(
      { channel: "ProgressChannel", room: "2" },
      { received: function() {
        this.setProgress(arguments[0])
       }}
    )
  }
})
```

But this gives me an error saying that `this.setProgress` is not a function, which is obvious since I'm calling it within the `create` method of App.cable.subscriptions.

How can I make this work? I realize I'm mixing things with my question, but I wanted to illustrate what my goal is. I simply want to know how to make the component's `progress` data to update, either from the outside, or from the component itself if I can make it find the function.

Comment: its $store not store. All Vue's built-in properties are accessed/declared with '$' sign

Comment: Well ... duh. Let me test that.

Answer (score 0):

You are *initializing* your data item to the value from the store:

```
  data () {
    return {
      progress: store.state.progress
    }
  }
```

Changes to the store will not propagate to your data item. You could eliminate the data item and just use `store.state.progress` where you need it, or you could create an `computed` that returns its value if you want a local single-name handle for it.